# Using R And XPATH To Count Ancestors Of All Nodes With Same Element Name

Tags: r, xml

I have an XML file that I need to parse such that it returns both the contents all nodes with a specific ID and the number of ancestors of that node. I am using R for the analysis, and I am familiar with the XML and XML2 packages.

My XML file looks like this:

```
<wc:COLLECTION xmlns:wc="mywebpage.com">
 <Object NAME="TREE" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
  <wc:INSTANCE>
   <name>Top_Level</name>
   <partType>Assembly</partType>
   <number>123455</number>
   <wt.part.WTPartUsageLink.uses>
    <wc:INSTANCE>
     <name>Component_1</name>
     <partType>component</partType>
     <number>123456</number>
    </wc:INSTANCE>
   </wt.part.WTPartUsageLink.uses>
   <wt.part.WTPartUsageLink.uses>
    <wc:INSTANCE>
     <name>SUBASSEMBLY</name>
     <partType>separable</partType>
     <number>123457</number>
      <wt.part.WTPartUsageLink.uses>
       <wc:INSTANCE>
        <name>Component_2</name>
        <partType>component</partType>
        <number>123458</number>
       </wc:INSTANCE>
      </wt.part.WTPartUsageLink.uses>
    </wc:INSTANCE>
   </wt.part.WTPartUsageLink.uses>
  </wc:INSTANCE>
 </Object NAME="TREE" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
<wc:COLLECTION xmlns:wc="mywebpage.com">
```

Ultimately, I would like to create a dataframe that looks like this:

| Number | Name | Count of Ancestors |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123455 | Top_Level | 0 |
| 123456 | Component_1 | 1 |
| 123457 | SUBASSEMBLY | 1 |
| 123458 | Component_2 | 2 |

I was successful using the XML2 package in R to gather all of the node contents for "number" and "name" using this approach:

```
library(XML2)
library(XML)
READ_MY_XML <-read_xml(MY_XML$content)
number <- as.character(xml_text(xml_find_all(READ_MY_XML, xpath = "//number")))
name <- as.character(xml_text(xml_find_all(READ_MY_XML, xpath = "//name")))
df <- tibble(number = number, name = name)
```

this yields 2 of the 3 columns that I require. The last is one that I require is the count of the ancestors.

In an attempt to count the ancestors I used the "XPATHSAPPLY" fuction. Here is my sample attempt:

```
MY_PARSED_XML <- xmlParse(MY_XML)
count_of_ancestors <- xpathSApply(MY_PARSED_XML, "count(//number/ancestor::*)", xmlValue)
```

This results in the overall count of all ancestors for "number" nodes. This count is a singular number, not a series of numbers that equal the overall count of nodes.

I also attempted to get the count of the ancestors for a single node by index with the thought that I could then loop through all index positions. Here is that attempt:

```
MY_PARSED_XML <- xmlParse(MY_XML)
count_of_ancestors  <- xpathSApply(MY_PARSED_XML, "count(./number[3]/ancestor::*)", xmlValue)
```

This results in "0", which is incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the xml2 library there is the `xml_parents()` function.  With this one can count the total number of parent nodes in the structure.  In this case you do need to adjust for the number parents to the "top_level".

```
library(xml2)
nodes <- xml_find_all(READ_MY_XML, xpath = ".//name")
number <- as.character(xml_text(xml_find_all(READ_MY_XML, xpath = "//number")))
name <- as.character(xml_text(xml_find_all(READ_MY_XML, xpath = "//name")))

#counts parents and then corrects for the structure
ancestors <- sapply(nodes, function(n) {
   temp <- n %>% xml_parents() %>% length()
   (temp-3)/2
})
df <- tibble(number = number, name = name, ancestors)

> df
# A tibble: 4 × 3
  number name        ancestors
  <chr>  <chr>           <dbl>
1 123455 Top_Level           0
2 123456 Component_1         1
3 123457 SUBASSEMBLY         1
4 123458 Component_2         2
```

Comment: Hi Dave2e, your answer works perfectly for my application. Thank you, this one had me stumped for a few weeks.